# Displaying levels of wav file

Tags: python, wav, levels

I want to read wav file and display levels of it. I know how to read frames, using wave module in python, but do not know what to deal with it. Any ideas will help.
Thanks

```
import wave
import struct
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wrd = wave.open("albatros.wav")

display = []
display2=[]
x = []

(nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes, comptype, compname) = wrd.getparams()

for i in range(0,int(nframes)):
    x.append(i)
    samplestring = wrd.readframes(1)
    display.append(struct.unpack('h',samplestring[:2])[0]);
    if(nchannels == 2):
        display2.append(struct.unpack('h',samplestring[2:4])[0])

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,display, 'k')

if (nchannels == 2):
    plt.figure(2)
    plt.plot(x,display2, 'k')

plt.show()

print (len(display))

wrd.close()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! To get proper help from community - please share the code you've tried.

Comment: here is code that displays all frames in graph

Comment: '*do not know what to deal with it*' I'm not sure what the exact question is. There is a problem with the unpacking in your program. It functions only with some kinds of wav files. Wav files come in many flavors, and it's not always easy to adapt. However, the code works for some of the wavs I tried.

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VpmYtO-xk_I   I need good article which explains how to obtain this levels